# how to move search box to the end line in html

Tags: html

Let me ask how I can move the search box to the end of the line (HTML)

[image]

Comment: paste your code plz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the search box with a class or ID, depending on which class or ID you have chosen. Let's assume you have chosen the ID called `searchform`
Then your CSS would be this:

```
#searchform {
float: right;
}
```

Comment: oh thank you very much <3

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please click on the upvote button and the checkmark as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your CSS:

```
.form-inline.my-2.my-lg-0 {
    float: right;
}
```